# How to resize brush width? - Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I can resize brush size in fabric.js, but after changing the brush size again, the drawn outline immediately moves a little to the left and a little up after being drawn!

> My code works fine in the initial setting of the brush size and I have
> no problem with it!
> `canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10;`

After resesize the brush size, the brush size changes again and works correctly, but the following problem occurs

```
function resize(){
   canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 20; // Resize 10 to 20
}
```

My problem **after resize** brush:
[image]

What should i do?

Comment: May this help you : https://jsfiddle.net/Fidel90/7kmf3jz2/3/

Comment: @skj Thank you very much! This is exactly what I want. The only problem I have is that when I add the codes of this editor to my own codes, the demo does not work. I just copied the displayed code into my editor and got incorrect output.

Comment: Post your own code, ill check it

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Turns out I was setting the brush size to a string value instead of an integer value.

It should be :
`canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;`
instead of:
`canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = '5';`

If you are getting the value from a form input. Remember to cast it into integer.
eg:
`canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = parseInt(input.value);`